# No more recaptcha global key option?

Tags: recaptcha

I am curious if there's still possibility to create global keys for reCaptcha.

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro) points it is possible, but I can find no way - no such option is there whenever I add a site.

Comment: Did you find a way to create global keys?

Comment: No, guess there's no such option anymore

Comment: Replaced by the Secure Token I guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191250/how-can-i-use-recaptcha-v2-on-a-large-number-of-domains

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google made **reCaptcha Global URL** possible again in 2016 for the I'm not a Robot checkbox:

- https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/domain_validation

Now to get the keys to work on every URL you have to go to: **"Advanced Settings"** for your key, and untick the **"Domain Name Validation"** box:

- https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

This is a **security hole**, so you are required to **check the hostname field** in your JSON response and reject any solutions that are coming from unexpected sources:

- https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api-response

Answer (score 1):

This option has dissapeared. In fact, google is deleting that info from documentation step by step. There is an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=global&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=194)

Maybe we can ask to reopen that option, or at least, to obtain some info why this option its gone

Answer (score 1):

Well the Secure Token would be the way to do this:

"A reCAPTCHA key is normally tied to a set of individual domains. However, you might have a large number of hosted domains and would like to have one key working on all of them - the solution is the secure token."
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/secure_token

A similar question ([How can I use reCAPTCHA v2 on a large number of domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191250/how-can-i-use-recaptcha-v2-on-a-large-number-of-domains)) has a PHP sample and a Java sample is in GitHub https://github.com/google/recaptcha-java/tree/master/appengine