# reCaptcha: allow for all domains or add via API

Tags: recaptcha

I'm using the new reCaptcha from Google (with the checkbox and NOT the one with the text to rewrite).
As I'm hosting multiple domains (a lot), I can't add all the domains in the admin panel.

**My question** :

- is it possible to allow the captcha for **all the domains** ?
- is there a way (API ?) to **add new domain** to my list ?

If not, can you recommand me an alternative for this reCaptcha that allows per default all the domains ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use reCAPTCHA v2 on a large number of domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191250/how-can-i-use-recaptcha-v2-on-a-large-number-of-domains)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>For multiple domains you can use the Secure Token method.
[Secure Token](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/secure_token)</del>  *(Deprecated)*

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks !

Comment: This is a deprecated feature.

Comment: That feature is no longer a thing, for future people check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191250/how-can-i-use-recaptcha-v2-on-a-large-number-of-domains

Comment: Secure token deprecated

Comment: So is this method still working? 
Is there an alternative (even from another captcha provider) if this one is no longer working? I have no possible way of knowing the domain name where the request is coming from in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 13):

> A reCAPTCHA key is normally tied to a set of individual domains.
>   However, if your list of valid domains is extremely long, fluid, or
>   unknown, we give you the option to turn off the domain name checking
>   on reCAPTCHA's end, and instead check on your server.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/domain_validation

Comment: If your list of domains is actually unknown, so you want to leave it blank in the registration, the msg "ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key" appears instead of the CAPTCHA, even with domain name checking disabled. If anyone knows of a currently working way around this, please speak up.

Comment: @enigment enter localhost for domain name

Comment: ...and untick the "Domain Name Validation" box

Comment: You're right that you need to do those things to allow access from localhost, but I don't think that allows access from ANY domain, which is what the question and and my comment are about. It permits localhost only.

Comment: Have you tested this or are you guessing?

Comment: Hmmm, I thought I had tested both localhost and blank with domain checking off, and neither worked. However, it appears I was wrong, or the API has been updated over the last few weeks, localhost does work on any domain. So thank you for poking me about this @Peca. The only mention of localhost in the docs that I'm aware of is this: 'If you would like to use "localhost" for development, you must add it to the list of domains.', which doesn't in the slightest way imply that that's what to use for a key to be usable on ALL domains, but if it works, great.

Comment: This is a deprecated feature of the reCAPTCHA API

Answer (score 2):

ReCaptcha actually allows you to add **up to** **50 domains**, all domains must be on a new line in the domain input box.

Domain registration also includes any and all sub-domains.

If necessary, you can disable domain name checking but it is **highly discouraged** since doing so creates a considerable security hole.

Google reCaptcha doc about domains: [**Domain/Package Name Validation**](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/domain_validation)  <sub><sup>(link updated)</sup></sub>

Comment: There is no option to disable domain or package name checking on Recaptcha Admin Console