# Recaptcha not working, though it works with the same code on another of my sites?

Tags: php, cakephp, recaptcha

So I recently had to add a recaptcha to my companies website, I had implemented this on another site in the past so I figured I would just use that code and replace the site keys and it would work.  So far it has not.

My companies website view:

```
                    <?php echo $this->Form->create(null, ['url' => ['controller' => 'Content', 'action' => 'qbsignup']]); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('full_name',['type'=>'text', 'required'=>true]); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('email',['type'=>'email', 'required'=>true]); ?>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->input('phone_number',['type'=>'text', 'required'=>false]); ?>

                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="mysitekey"></div>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Sign Up'); ?>
                    <small>By submitting this form, you agree to allow Net2Sky to contact you about QuickBooks related information.</small>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

While this is my companies controller:

```
if(!empty($this->request->data)) {
            //verify google recaptcha
            $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
            $privatekey='myprivatekey';

            $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".($this->data['g-recaptcha-response'])."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            //$url."?secret".$privatekey."&response=".($this->data['g-recaptcha-response'])."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            $data2 =json_decode($response, true);

            if(intval($data2["success"])==1){
                $error=0;
            }else{
                $error=1;
                $this->Session->setFlash("Please fill out the Security CAPTCHA and try again.");
            }

            if ($error == 0) {
            foreach($this->request->data as $n => $m):
                $body .= "<b>" . $n . ":</b> " . $m . "<br />";
            endforeach;
            $body .= "</p><p>Date Of Submission: " . date("m/d/Y H:i") . "<p>";

            $email = new Email('default');

            $result = $email ->from(['aemailaddress' => 'Our Site'])
                    ->to('aemailaddress')
                    ->emailFormat('both')
                    ->subject('QuickBooks Signup')
                    ->send($body);


            if($result) {
                $this->redirect('/qbsignup/'.$this->request->data['full_name']);
            }
            else {
                $this->redirect('/qbsignup');
            }

        }
        else {
            $this->set('name', $fullname);
        }
        }
```

So I am a little confused why it does not work and only returns failed code.

Here is the info for the other site where the code works:
View:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(['url' => '/Forms/contact']); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Contact.name', array('label' => 'Name', 'size' => '33', 'required' => 'required')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Contact.phone', array('label' => 'Phone Number', 'size' => '20', 'required' => 'required')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Contact.email', array('label' => 'E-mail Address', 'size' => '22', 'required' => 'required')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Contact.topic', array('label' => 'What service are you interested in?', 'options'=>
        array('Tree Removal'=>'Tree Removal','Tree Trimming'=>'Tree Trimming','Mulch Delivery'=>'Mulch Delivery','Emergency Service'=>'Emergency Service','Other'=>'Other'))); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Contact.needs', array('label' => 'How may we help you?', 'after' => '<p style="padding: 0;margin: 0; font-size: 80%;">(we\'ll respond within 1 hour or less between 7 am and 7 pm)</p>', 'rows' => '5', 'cols' => '45', 'required' => 'required')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('Contact.page', array('value' => 'home')); ?>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="sitekey"></div>

<?php echo $this->Form->submit(); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

And it's controller:

```
        if (!empty($this->data['Contact'])) {

            //verify google recaptcha
            $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
            $privatekey='myprivatekey';

            $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".($this->data['g-recaptcha-response'])."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            //$url."?secret".$privatekey."&response=".($this->data['g-recaptcha-response'])."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
            $data2 =json_decode($response, true);

            if(intval($data2["success"])==1){
                $error=0;
            }else{
                $error=1;
                $this->Session->setFlash("Please fill out the Security CAPTCHA and try again.");
            }

            if ($error == 0) {
            // Craft e-mail
            $subject = "Website Contact";

            $message = "";

            foreach ($this->data['Contact'] as $key => $value) {
                $message .= '{' . $key . '} = > ' . $value . "\n";  
            }
            $message .= '{timestamp} => ' . date('F j, Y \a\t g:i a', time()) . "\n";
            $message .= '{sent from IP} => ' . substr($this->request->clientIp(), 0, 12);


//          $this->Email->to = array('aemailaddress');
//                        $this->Email->from = $this->data['Contact']['email'];
//          $this->Email->template = 'default';
//          $this->Email->subject = $subject;
            if(substr($this->request->clientIp(), 0, 12) != "aipaddress" && 
            substr($this->request->clientIp(), 0, 11) != "aipaddress"){
                $message .= '{timestamp} => ' . date('F j, Y \a\t g:i a', time()) . "\n";
            $message .= '{sent from IP} => ' . substr($this->request->clientIp(), 0, 12);

            $Email = new CakeEmail();
            $Email ->from(array('aemailaddress' => 'Website Submission'))
                    ->to(array('aemailaddress'))
                    ->subject($subject)
                    ->sender('aemailaddress', 'Website Submission')
                    ->config(array('from' => 'aemailaddress', 'transport'=>'Smtp'))
                    ->send($message);
            //$this->Email->send($message);
                      //  print_r($this->Email);
                      //  exit();
                        $this->Session->setFlash("Thank you for your submission");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $this->Session->setFlash("Nice try, spammer.");
                    }
                        $this->redirect("/");
            }
        }
```

If anyone has any ideas why one works and the other doesn't it would be very helpful.  Or if anyone knows why one doesn't work and can assist in the fix.

Comment: `print_r($data2);` see if you get any error messages

Comment: Are you using the same private key ? You might need to add your company domain to your google admin page. See [reCaptcha: allow for all domains or add via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881789/recaptcha-allow-for-all-domains-or-add-via-api)

Comment: @smith `code`Array
(
    [success] =&gt; 
    [error-codes] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; missing-input-response
        )

)

Comment: @np87 yes I am not using the same private key for both websites, I have created a different comapny domain for both sites and am using different keys for each of them.

Comment: " missing-input-response" well there you go

Comment: @smith doesn't that mean it thinks I didn't click the captcha?  But I did click the captcha.

Comment: `$this->data['g-recaptcha-response']` is empty

Comment: Any idea why it is filled on the one site and not the other?  Or how to fix?